# Netbeans 7.3.1 - Group maven modules

Tags: maven, netbeans, module

does anyone know if it is possible in Netbeans 7 to group modules of a multimodule maven project (like e.g. in Intellij)? Right now every module is kind of like its own project...

Another issue: Is it somehow possible to access the maven targets without going through the netbeans IDE goals via rightclick? I would like to have a window with a list of all maven targets (clean, validate, compile etc.) and use them via click... Is that possible in Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another view to multimodule maven projects is the plugin Geertjan provides https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/maven_integrated_view_for_netbeans
But it is experimental.